# VueJS + ElementUI - el-table resizing issue in div

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, element-ui

I have to place two tables (ElementUI's `el-table`) next to eachother. No problem, I just put them in a `div` and split the div using `flexbox`.

```
<div>
    <el-table />
    <el-table />
</div>
```

With the following css for the container-div:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
gap: 30px;
```

*Works perfectly well*.

I also need to place a heading above each table, so I would like to wrap each table in a div and split that div using `flexbox` and `flex-direction: column`.

My template:

```
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <div>Title Left</div>
        <el-table />
    </div>
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <div>Title Right</div>
        <el-table />
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
.outerContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 30px;
}
.innerContainer{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
}
```

**Problem:**
When I increase the viewport-width (by hiding the sidebar or increasing the width of my browser), the tables expand just perfectly. But once I try to reduce the width of my page, the tables won't shrink back down and overflow outside the viewport. Does anybody know why wrapping a table in a div messes with it's responsiveness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I solved setting a `max-width` to the containers, for example

```
.outerContainer, .innerContainer {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Try it and let me know if it works also for you :)

Comment: I never tried max-width. That makes sense! Thank you for the tip. I'll be sure to test that the next time I run into that problem.